# Proof of an Equivalence for Irreducible Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

I am wondering if my proof for the following proposition is valid, and I am looking for any hints or suggestions if there are problems with it. I have tried googling this proof to see if I can verify mine with a known one to validate it, but have been unsuccessful.

**Proposition:** Let $\Bbb F$ be a field and $p(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$ be a polynomial with $\deg(p(x))\geq 1$. Prove that $p(x)$ is irreducible if and only if for every $g(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$, either $p(x)\mid g(x)$ or $\gcd (p(x),g(x))=1$.

**Proof:** I show that these are equivalent by showing their negations are equivalent. That is, $(A\iff B)\iff (\lnot A\iff\lnot B)$. So the proposition is equivalent to: $p(x)$ is reducible if and only if there exists $g(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$ such that $p(x)\nmid g(x)$ and $\gcd(p(x),g(x))\neq 1$. $\color{red}{\text{First of all, is this actually equivalent to the original proposition?}}$ Now we prove the forward implication of the "not proposition", so suppose that $p(x)$ is reducible in $\Bbb F[x]$. Then $p(x)=f(x)h(x)$ for some $f(x),h(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$ with $1\leq\deg(f(x)),\deg(h(x))<\deg(p(x))$. So if we choose $g(x)=f(x)$, then $p(x)\nmid f(x)$ since $\deg(p(x))>\deg(f(x))$ and $\gcd(p(x),f(x))=f(x)$, where $\deg(f(x))\geq 1\implies \gcd(p(x),f(x))\neq1$. This completes this part of the proof, as we have found a satisfactory $g(x)$. Now we prove the reverse implication of the "not proposition", so suppose that there exists $g(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$ such that $p(x)\nmid g(x)$ and $\gcd(p(x),g(x))\neq 1$. Let $d(x)=\gcd(p(x),g(x))$, then $\deg(d(x))\geq 1$. So clearly $d(x)\mid p(x)$, which means that $p(x)=d(x)k(x)$ for some $k(x)\in\Bbb F[x]$. If $\deg(k(x))=0$, then $p(x)$ and $d(x)$ are associates, so $d(x)\mid g(x)\implies p(x)\mid g(x)$, which cannot happen. Thus, we must have $\deg(k)\geq 1$. Thus, $\deg(d(x)),\deg(k(x))\geq 1$, so we must have $1\leq\deg(d(x)),\deg(k(x))<\deg(p(x))$ since $\deg(p(x))=\deg(g(x))+\deg(k(x))$, and degrees are nonnegative integers. Thus, $p(x)$ factors to polynomials of lower degree, so $p(x)$ is reducible. This establishes the "not proposition", which is equivalent to the original proposition, so we are done.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Are you familiar with ideals?

Comment: @BillDubuque No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the right idea. More simply, note that $\,(p,g)=p\iff p\mid g,\,$ so $\,p\nmid g\iff (p,g)\,$ is a *proper* factor of $p.\,$ That combined with $\,(p,g)\neq 1$ implies that $\,(p,g)\,$ is a nontrivial factor of $g$. So the equivalence boils down to: $\,p\,$ is irred iff $p$ has a nontrivial factor $g$ iff $\,(p,g)\neq 1$ and $\,(p,g)\neq p$

Answer (score 0):

I have not examined your work. But we can do the following:

(A1). When $p$ is irreducible with $deg (p)>0$: If $0\ne b\in F[x]$ with $deg (b)<deg (p)$ then $\gcd (p,b)=1.$ Because any divisor of $p$ whose degree is $\leq deg (b)$ is a divisor of $p$ whose degree is $< deg (p)$ and therefore must be a non-zero constant, because $p$ is irreducible .

(A2). Whenever $p,g \in F[x]$ with $\deg p>0$   there exist $a,b\in F[x]$ with $g=ap+b$ and $deg(b)<deg (p).$ (For a rigorous proof see part (D), below.)

(B). If $p$ is irreducible with $deg (p)>0$ and $p\not | \; g ,$ then by (A2) let $g=ap+b$ with $deg (b)<deg (p).$ We have $b\ne 0 .$ (Else $g=ap+b=ap$ is divisible by $p$, contrary to hypothesis).

Now $\gcd (g,p)$ divides $p$ and also divides $(g-ap)=b$ with $b\ne 0$ and $deg (b)<deg (p)$. So  $\gcd(g,p)| \gcd (b,p)$.And by (A1),$\gcd (b,p)=1$, so $\gcd (g,p)=1.$

Summary: If $p$ is irreducible with $deg(p)>0$ then $p\not |\;g\implies \gcd(g,p)=1 .$

(C). If $p$ is reducible then $p=gh$ where $g,h$ are non-constants in $F[x].$ We have $p\not | \;g$. (Else for some $j\in F[x]$ with $j\ne 0$ we have $p= gh=(jp)h,$ implying $$deg (p)=deg(j)+deg(p)+ deg (h)\geq deg(p)+deg (h)>deg (p)$$ which is absurd.) And we have $\gcd(g,p)=g$ with $deg(g)>0$ so $\gcd (p,g)\ne 1.$

Summary: If $p$ is reducible with $deg(p)>0$ there exists $g$ with $p\not |\;g$ and $\gcd (g,p)\ne 1.$

(D). Addendum to Part (A2).  With $deg (p)=m>0,$ let $n$ be the least degree of any $b\in F[x]$ such that there exists $a\in F[x]$ satisfying $g=ap+b.$ (Note that $n$ exists, as $g=ap+b$ does have a solution, e.g, $a=0, b=g.$).

Let $g=ap+b$ with $deg(b)=n.$ Suppose (by contradiction) that $n\geq m.$

We have  $b=B_nx^n +b'$ with $0\ne B_n\in F$ and $deg(b')\leq n-1.$ We have $p=P_mx^m+p'$ where $0\ne P_n\in F$ and $deg (p')\leq m-1.$

Let $a'= a+x^{n-m}B_n/P_n.$ Then $g=a'p+b'$ with $deg(b')<n$, contrary to the minimality of $ n.$ So by contradiction, we must have $n<m.$